# При компиляции проекта Maven выдает ошибку

Tags: java, linux, maven

OS Linux - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
При компиляции проекта Maven выдает ошибку

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Unable to load cache item
[ERROR] Caused by: Could not initialize class com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper
```

java -version

```
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

mvn -version

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17, vendor: BellSoft, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java17-amd64
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.11.0-37-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep 'java.home'

```
java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java17-amd64
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439975/5909792 ?

Comment: Получилось ли разобраться с 17ой java ?

Comment: одни проблемы решил, появились новые - при сборке проекта, почему-то не все зависимости подтягиваются. Но я так понимаю, что это уже другой вопрос надо создавать.